# Get clicked position from NSTableView doubleAction

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

Apparently if you `setDoubleAction()` on an `NSTableView` you can use [`clickedRow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1527357-clickedrow) to get the row that was double-clicked, but is there any way to get the actual position of the double-click? An app I am working on has several things in the cell and I want double-clicking on different areas to do different things.

Comment: See gesture sender's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the current event:

```
NSEvent* currentEvent = [NSApp currentEvent];
NSPoint eventLocation = currentEvent.locationInWindow;
NSPoint viewClickLoc = [self.view convertPoint:eventLocation fromView:nil];
```

Comment: Amazing thanks! (Sorry if this was a really noob question - I don't actually know Objective-C - just trying to add a feature to [GitX](https://github.com/gitx/gitx).)